# how to remove curly braces in php

Tags: php, regex, explode, implode, crocodoc

I am having one variable 
$uuid={"uuid": "**28fb72ed-0e97-4e78-9404-b676289b33ee**"};

which i am getting after execution

i need to extract 28fb72ed-0e97-4e78-9404-b676289b33ee just the number

how do you do it in php any ideas

i am including some code here 
i am using crcodoc viewer and i have generated the uuid using crocodoc api 
now to check the status i need the uuid seperatly ... it is passing the whole variable 
i have to split and get the uuid alone

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array('Accept: application/json', 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST'));
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$param);
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $frameUrl);   
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                $uuids = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $uuids;
 echo "\n\nchecking status of : ", $uuids;
$status =getStatus($uuids,$api_url,$myToken);
```

probably regex or explode () or implode () function should be used here

can someone help ..

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 solutions.

Easier with JSON:

```
$str = '{"uuid": "28fb72ed-0e97-4e78-9404-b676289b33ee"}';
$obj  = json_decode($str);
echo $obj->uuid;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
28fb72ed-0e97-4e78-9404-b676289b33ee
```

Second with Regex

```
$str = '{"uuid": "28fb72ed-0e97-4e78-9404-b676289b33ee"}';

preg_match('/"uuid": "([^"]+?)"/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => "uuid": "28fb72ed-0e97-4e78-9404-b676289b33ee" [1] => 28fb72ed-0e97-4e78-9404-b676289b33ee )
```

`$matches[1]` has got value you need.

Comment: That did the trick .. thanks for explaining in detail both are working i am going with JSON trick... it seems to have less line of code and do the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 echo $uuid->uuid;
```

may it will give you

Answer (score -1):

This code will solve your bug:

```
preg_replace('/{}/', '', $uuids);
```